# Prove if $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, then the image is also compact.

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, compactness

I am not 100% sure about my proof, ideally I would like some hints/confirmation on my proof.

Proof:

Since I want to show $f(S)$ is compact I need to show it is closed and bounded.

- Closure

Consider a sequence $(x_n) \subset S$ where  $x_n \to L \in S$ (by compactness). Since $L \in S$ we have that since the function is continuous $f(L) \in f(S)$.

Then using sequential continuity on this sequence  $f(x_n) \to f(L) \in f(S)$. Since we can represent any sequence in $f(S)$ as the image of any given sequence in $S$ the set $f(S)$ is closed.

- Bounded

Since $S$ is bounded and $f$ continuous, suppose $s^*$ maximises the function $f$ on $S$ - if $f(s^*) \to \infty$ $f$ is not continuous. Since $max(S)$ and $min(S)$ are finite numbers, we cannot have divergence to infinity of the function over the elements of $s$, so $f(s^*)$ is the upper bound of $f(S)$. Repeating for the lower bound I have that S is bounded.

Is my proof correct. I have concerns that my proof for bounded is not very well worded, also I feel like my proof for closure may miss certain cases.

Comment: Regarding the closure, you want to show that every converging sequence in $f(S)$ has its limit again in $f(S)$. Currently that is not what you are showing, also make sure you understand that $f(S) \neq S$, maybe thats just a typo.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(s^*)\to\infty$? What is the variable for this convergence?

Comment: The idea is right, altough the overall proof could be written better. Just to see if I can help: what's, for you, the definition of a compact set? The ones satisfying any open cover has a finite subcover?

Comment: @FranCruz the used definition is "closed and bounded", apparently. Which is allowed on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @FranCruz My definition of a compact set is one which is closed: any convergent sequence in the set's limit is also in the set, and bounded.

Comment: @Govind75 Okay. That definition is correct in $\mathbb{R}$, but ain't general. There's a nice and shot proof for $f(S)$ to be compact when $f$ is continuos and $S$ is compact (in the general definition). Remember me until the day you learn it haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then using sequential continuity on this sequence $f(x_n) \to f(L) \in S$.

For closure what you want to show is that if $f(x_n) \to L$ then $L \in f(S)$.

> $f(s^*) \to \infty$

This is meaningless to me. $f(s^*)$ is constant it does not "tend to" anything.

> Since $\max(S)$ and $\min(S)$ are finite numbers, we cannot have divergence to infinity of the function over the elements of $S$

Why not, *exactly*? This is, after all, what you are trying to prove and just stating that it's true is not a proof.

---

I think the better way to look at this is through the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. To show $f(S)$ is compact you need to show that every sequence $y_n = f(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence and here you can use a convergent subsequence of $x_n$ to reach that conclusion.

Comment: Okay, so trying to apply what you said above. If I consider any sequence $x_n \subset S$ and $y_n = f(x_n) \subset f(S)$, since $S$ is bounded there exists a convergent subsequence $x_{n(i)}$ via the BWT s.t. $x_{n(i)} \to L$. Since $S$ is compact $L \in S$, taking the image of our subsequence $y_{n(j)} = f(x_{n(i)})$ yields (via seq. continuity) that $y_{n(j)} \to f(L)$. Since $L \in S$, $f(L) \in f(S)$, hence $f(S)$ is compact? I feel as if I am missing something...

Comment: @Govind75 Slow down. You want to consider any sequence from $f(S)$. It just happens that such sequences arise from sequences in $S$. But then, like you say, if $y_n$ is a sequence in $f(S)$ and $y_n = f(x_n)$ (there might be multiple $x$'s to each $y$, we need to make a choice) then $y_n$ has a convergent subsequence $f(x_{n_k})$. So every sequence in $f(S)$ has a convergent subsequence therefore, by Bolzano-Weierstrass, $f(S)$ is compact. If you haven't seen the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem this will be hard to understand.

Comment: But you can also use this convergent subsequence fact to show that $f(S)$ is closed and bounded. E.g. to show it is bounded suppose you have a sequence $f(x_n)$ which is unbounded. But that sequence has a convergent subsequence and a convergent subsequence must converge to some finite number.

Comment: I've seen the Bolzano-Weierstrass but using your method do I not need to then show that every sequence $y_n \subset f(S)$ has a sequence $x_n \subset S$ such that $y_n = f(x_n)$? Also would I need to show still that $f(S)$ is bounded as bounded $\implies$ BWT?

Comment: @Govind75 That is correct. So $y_n \in f(S) = \{f(x) : x \in S\}$ means that there exists some $x_n \in S$ with $y_n = f(x_n)$.

Comment: Ah I understand now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea for the proof is fine *as long* as you are only concerned about finite dimensional cases. However in general closed and bounded is not a sufficient condition for compactness (in particular in infinite dimensional spaces).

The proof itself also makes some errors, for example what @Max already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with $\Bbb R$. Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuosu function between spaces and $S \subseteq X$ compact.

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $f[S]$. Then $\{f^{-1}[U]\mid U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ is an open cover of $S$ by continuity of $f$ and so has a finite subcover $f^{-1}[U_1],\ldots f[U_n]$. Then $\{U_1, \ldots, U_n\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}$. Hence $f[S]$ is compact.

This is the essence.